# How to bind Entry to Xam.Plugins.Settings using BindingContext

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Binding seems somewhat more confusing in Xamarin Forms compared to C#. I installed [Xam.Plugins.Settings](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugins.Settings/). I simply want to bind bind an `<Entry>` to one of my settings. Here's what I have in my XAML:

```
<Grid BindingContext="{HelloWorld.Helpers.Settings}">
    ...
    <Entry Placeholder="ESN"
               Text="{Binding Path=Esn, Mode=TwoWay}" 
               ...
     />
</Grid>
```

And here's my code behind:

```
namespace HelloWorld.Helpers
{
    public static class Settings
    {
        private static ISettings AppSettings
        {
            get
            {
                return CrossSettings.Current;
            }
        }

        #region Setting Constants

        private const string EsnKey = "esn_key";
        private static readonly string EsnDefault = string.Empty;

        #endregion

        public static string Esn
        {
            get
            {
                return AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault<string>(EsnKey, EsnDefault);
            }
            set
            {
                AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue<string>(EsnKey, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the error: **Position 7:15. Type HelloWorld.Helpers.Settings not found**

[This tutorial](https://blog.xamarin.com/introduction-to-data-binding/) shows an example of how to set the BindingContext dynamically, but as you can see, the Settings class is static, and so I can't call `new`. I also want to be able to set the binding in the XAML. I then referred to [this tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/), so I tried to set the value of BindingContext in the XAML to `{x:Static HelloWorld.Helpers.Settings}`, but I get the same error.

All I want to do is map `HelloWorld.Helpers.Settings.Esn` to this `<Entry>`.

Any advice? I'm totally new to Xamarin, and I have very little C# experience.

Thanks in advance!

**Update 1 5/26**
@Alessandro solution works. I prefer not to have to write getters and setters again, since they're already written in Settings, but it works. I didn't have to use INPC though. Here is the code for my ContentPage in case anyone else has the same issue. Thanks.

```
namespace HelloWorld
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Configuration : ContentPage
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new MySettings();
        }
    }

    public class MySettings
    {
        public string Esn
        {
            get { return HelloWorld.Helpers.Settings.Esn; }
            set { HelloWorld.Helpers.Settings.Esn = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

And then I removed the BindingContext property from within my XAML, since it's being set in the code behind.

Update 2 5/26
I just changed `public static class Settings` to `public class Settings` and `public static string Esn` to `public string Esn`. Then that prevents the need for MySettings. And instead I write `BindingContext = new Settings();`

I'm not sure why the plugin developer used static instead, but it was a simple solution it seems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use a Class "MySettings" that use "Settings" and implement INotifyPropertyChanged (I use PropertyChanged.Fody for INPC)

```
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class MySettings
{
    public string Url {
        get { return Settings.Url; } // These are yours "Settings"
        set { Settings.Url = value; }
    }
    public int Port {
        get { return Settings.Port; }
        set { Settings.Port = value; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove `static` keywords from `public static class Settings` and `public static string Esn`
2. In the constructor for your `ContentPage`, add `BindingContext = new Settings()`
3. Remove the `BindingContext` property from the XAML

That's it.